# Is it possible to use 1 microphone in 2 applications at the same time

Tags: pi-3, alsa

I have an [AlexaPi](https://github.com/sammachin/AlexaPi/) running, but I also want a voice activated (and controlled) radio machine.

The radio part is sorted, and so is the AlexaPi, but there is a problem.

Running them both at ones presents me with the error

`alsaaudio.ALSAAudioError: Device or resource busy`.

I have considered moving them into the same file but that would be very difficult, considering the AlexaPi is GPIO activated.

Is it possible to use the mic in the two places at once?

One is always listening, the other isn't.

if that can't be done, could it be possible to, when I push the GPIO button to make the AlexaPi listen, have it take control of the mic for the duration of the button being pushed, then return it to the other?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You may be interested in this: [ALSA microphone recording from more than application simotaneously](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=159492).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You should used the dsnoop alsa plugin. This will allow you to open the same device twice in different applications.

Here is an example :
arecord -Ddsnoop -f cd test.wav

Comment: Thanks, but I got this ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:961:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playba                                                      ck stream

Comment: What does arecord -L report ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jfXqpeiM

Comment: The USB camera is my microphone

Comment: The actual line that initiates the recording is `inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL, device)` I am pretty sure

Comment: Sorry, that should have been dsnoop, not dmix ... check here for more info : http://alsa.opensrc.org/Dsnoop

Comment: From your pastebin.com link, I think you should try "arecord -Ddsnoop:CARD=camera,DEV=0". If you can change the device which is opened in your apps, then set them to that device.

Comment: Sorry for super late reply, trying that I got ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
arecord: main:722: audio open error: Device or resource busy

Comment: I just tested on a different system. Dsnoop allows you to open the same recording device more then once. Are you sure nothing else is using the native "hw" device and locking it ?